# How to install Skype version 4 in Kubuntu 12.04?

Tags: kubuntu, skype

I 've tried to install Skype in my Kubuntu version 12.04, but it will not even start to install. I took of course the .deb version (to be precise the file: 
' skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_i386.deb '), made that file executable and double-clicked on it.
..... no reaction!...
What to do now? With the steps mentioned above I succeeded Skype to get installed and working in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you try 'sudo dpkg –install skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_i386.deb'

Answer (score 4):

From [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype):

You need to add an additional repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

And then you should be able to add it from `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```